# Get the longest logon time of a given user using awk

Tags: bash, awk

My task is to write a bash script, using awk, to find the longest logon of a given user ("still logged in" does not count), and print the `month` `day` `IP` `logon time in minutes`.

Sample input: `./scriptname.sh username1`

Content of `last username1`:

```
username1       pts/        IP      Apr     2       ..      ..      ..      ..      (00.03)

username1       pts/        IP      Apr     3       ..      ..      ..      ..      (00.13)

username1       pts/        IP      Apr     5       ..      ..      ..      ..      (12.00)

username1       pts/        IP      Apr     9       ..      ..      ..      ..      (12.11)
```

Sample output:

```
Apr 9 IP 731
```

(note: 12 hours and 11 minutes is in total 731 minutes)

I have written this script, but a bunch of errors pop up, and I am really confused:

```
#!/bin/bash

usr=$1

last $usr | grep -v "still logged in" | awk 'BEGIN {max=-1;}
                                                {
                                                h=substr($10,2,2);
                                                min=substr($10,5,2) + h/60;
                                                }
                                                (max < min){
                                                max = min;
                                                }
                                                END{
                                                maxh=max/60;
                                                maxmin=max-maxh;
                                                ($maxh == 0 && $maxmin >=10){
                                                        last $usr | grep "00:$maxmin" | awk '{print $5," ",$6," ", $3," ",$maxmin}'
                                                        exit 1
                                                }
                                                ($maxh == 0 $$ $maxmin < 10){
                                                        last $usr | grep "00:0$maxmin" | awk '{print $5," ",$6," ",$3," ",$maxmin}'
                                                        exit 1
                                                }
                                                ($maxh < 10 && $maxmin == 0){
                                                        last $usr | grep "0$maxh:00" | awk '{print $5," ",$6," ",$3," ",$maxmin}'
                                                        exit 1
                                                }
                                                ($maxh < 10 && $maxmin < 10){
                                                        last $usr | grep "0$maxh:0$maxmin" | awk '{print $5," ",$6," ",$3," ",$maxmin}'
                                                        exit 1
                                                }
                                                ($maxh >= 10 && $maxmin < 10){
                                                        last $usr | grep "$maxh:0$maxmin" | awk '{print $5," ",$6," ",$3," ",$maxmin}'
                                                        exit 1
                                                }
                                                ($maxh >=10 && $maxmin >= 10){
                                                        last $usr | grep "$maxh:$maxmin" | awk '{print $5," ",$6," ",$3," ",$maxmin}'
                                                        exit 1
                                                }
                                                }'
```

**So a bit of explaining of how I imagined this would work:**

After the initialization, I want to find the `(hh:mm)` column of the `last $usr` command, save the `h` and `min` of every line, find the biggest number (in minutes, meaning it is the longest logon time).

After I found the longest logon time (in minutes, stored in the variable `max`), I then have to reformat the only minutes format to `hh:mm` to be able to use a grep, use the last command again, but now only searching for the line(s) that contain the `max` logon time, and print all of the needed information in the `month` `day` `IP` `logon time in minutes` format, using another `awk`.

**Errors I get when running this code**: A bunch of syntax errors when I try using `grep` and `awk` inside the original `awk`.

Comment: Your code will be easier to read if you don't indent your awk script by 50 blanks or whatever that is and you do indent the blocks of code within `{...}` [airs.

Comment: [edit] your question to tell us what the output should be if the user logged in twice for the same longest duration each time but on different dates or different IP addresses (first one? last one? both? something else?). Also, show different IP address in your example, don't just say "IP", so we can see WHICH IP is being printed in the output.

Comment: Since your initial piped grep command is stripping a line that contains `still logged in`, that must be possible to appear in your input so please [edit] your question to include a line like that in your sample input. Also show us what the output should be if there is no input to process for the given user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

awk is not shell. You can't directly call tools like `last`, `grep` and `awk` from `awk` any more than you could call them directly from a `C` program.

Using any awk in any shell on every Unix box and assuming if multiple rows have the max time you'd want all of them printed and that if no timestamped rows are found you want something like `No matching records` printed (easy tweak if not, just tell us your requirements for those cases and include them in the example in your question):

```
last username1 |
awk '
    /still logged in/ {
        next
    }
    {
        split($NF,t,/[().]/)
        cur = (t[2] * 60) + t[3]
    }
    cur >= max {
        out = ( cur > max ? "" : out ORS ) $4 OFS $5 OFS $3 OFS cur
        max = cur
    }
    END {
        print (out ? out : "No matching records")
    }
'
Apr 9 IP 731
```

Comment: Thank you! could you explain the "ORS" and "OFS" syntax? Also, how do the ? : operators work (are these the do this ? `fnc` else : `fnc` ) ?

Comment: You're welcome. `ORS` and `OFS` are defined in the awk man page and manual, see https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Output-Separators, and `? :` is just a ternary operator like in many languages, see [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F:](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F:). Let me know if you have any specific questions after reading those references.

Answer (score 1):

If `gnu-awk` is available, you might use a pattern with 2 capture groups for the numbers in the last field. In the END block print the format that you want.

If in this example, `file` contains the example content, and the last column contains the logon:

```
awk '
match ($(NF), /\(([0-9]+)\.([0-9]+)\)/, a) {
  hm = (a[1] * 60) + a[2]
  if(hm > max) {max = hm; line = $0;}
}
END {
  n = split(line,a,/[[:space:]]+/)
  print a[3], a[4], a[5], max
}
' file
```

Output

```
IP Apr 9 731
```

Comment: @EdMorton I assumed reading `12.11` meant "expl: 12 hours and 11 minutes is in total 731 minutes" Those are valid points in your comments though, I changed it to an implementation using gnu-awk with a pattern and capture groups (Although your answer reads like sunshine on a cloudy day)

Comment: Ah, you're right on the hrs and mins, my mistake, I misunderstood what the OP meant by `logon time in minutes` at the start of the question - they're describing the output not the input.

Answer (score 0):

#### Testing `last` command in my machine:

Using Red Hat Linux 7.8
Got the following output:

```
user0022 pts/1        10.164.240.158   Sat Apr 25 19:32 - 19:47  (00:14)
user0022 pts/1        10.164.243.80    Sat Apr 18 22:31 - 23:31 (1+01:00)
user0022 pts/1        10.164.243.164   Sat Apr 18 19:21 - 22:05  (02:43)
user0011 pts/0        10.70.187.1      Thu Nov 21 15:26 - 18:37  (03:10)
user0011 pts/0        10.70.187.1      Thu Nov  7 16:21 - 16:59  (00:38)
astukals pts/0        10.70.187.1      Mon Oct  7 19:10 - 19:13  (00:03)
reboot   system boot  3.10.0-957.10.1. Mon Oct  7 22:09 - 14:30 (156+17:21)
astukals pts/0        10.70.187.1      Mon Oct  7 18:56 - 19:08  (00:12)
reboot   system boot  3.10.0-957.10.1. Mon Oct  7 21:53 - 19:08  (-2:-44)
IT       pts/0        10.70.187.1      Mon Oct  7 18:50 - 18:53  (00:03)
IT       tty1                          Mon Oct  7 18:48 - 18:49  (00:00)
user0022 pts/1        30.30.30.168     Thu Apr 16 09:43 - 14:54  (05:11)
user0022 pts/1        30.30.30.59      Wed Apr 15 11:48 - 04:59  (17:11)
user0022 pts/1        30.30.30.44      Tue Apr 14 19:03 - 04:14  (09:11)
```

Found time format is `DD+HH:MM` appears only when `DD` is not zero.

Found there are additional technical users: `IT`, `system`, `reboot` need to filtered.

#### Suggesting solution:

```
last | awk 'BEGIN {FS="[ ()+:]*"}
/reboot|system|still/{next}
{ print $5 OFS $6 OFS $3 OFS $(NF-1) + ($(NF-2) * 60) + ($(NF-3) * 60 * 24)}
' |sort -nk 4| head -1
```

##### Result:

```
Apr 15 30.30.30.59 85991
```